# Does calloc on an already allocated block of memory invoke a duplicate allocation?

Tags: c

I've already allocated a block of memory for 1024 `char` elements. `*p` is pointing on its first address.
Now I want to set all values to zero. If I'd use
`p = (char *) calloc(1024, sizeof(char))`
Would it reuse the already allocated block of memory or would I allocate 1024 new bytes in addition somewhere else and change the address `*p` is pointing to? And if that's what's happening, what happens with the old block? Because I literally couldn't call `free()` on it anymore.

Comment: ***How*** would you do "calloc on an already allocated block"? Do you mean you want to *reassign the pointer*? Please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly try to create a [mcve] to show us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does calloc on an already allocated block of memory invoke a duplicate allocation?

No it does not. You lose the old memory location.

> Would it reuse the already allocated block of memory or would I allocate 1024 new bytes?

Again, no it would not. You get a new memory location.

> What happens with the old block?

There will be a memory leak because there is no way to get access to it again.

> I literally couldn't call `free()` on it anymore.

You are right here.

The man page says:

```
DESCRIPTION
       operation is performed.

       The calloc() function allocates memory for an array of nmemb elements of size bytes  each
       and  returns  a pointer to the allocated memory.  The memory is set to zero.  If nmemb or
       size is 0, then calloc() returns either NULL, or a unique pointer value that can later be
       successfully passed to free().


RETURN VALUE
       The malloc() and calloc() functions return a pointer to the allocated  memory,  which  is
       suitably aligned for any built-in type.  On error, these functions return NULL.  NULL may
       also be returned by a successful call to malloc() with a size of zero, or by a successful
       call to calloc() with nmemb or size equal to zero.
```

Comment: These types of questions always remind me to be grateful that `valgrind` exists.